# How to Destory and Initialize Reveal.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, reveal.js

I am using the [Reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/) for slide show. I have initailized the Reveal using the below code

```
Reveal.initialize({
                        history: false,
                        center: false,
                        controls: true,
                        mouseWheel: true,
                        transition: 'slide',
                    });
```

Once the slide show is completed i need to destory the `Reveal` (Stop/Close) and want to Initalize/Start whenever I want. How can I do this?